# Show whole numbers with fixed decimal places in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers, rounding, number-formatting

I want to build a function which can take any number and return it with two decimal places. Importantly, I want to be able to have two 0s, e.g. 150.00.

I have tried using toFixed(2) but it returns a string which is not acceptable in this instance. I have tried converting the output of toFixed() with Number() but from what I can tell this converts 150.00 back to 150.

```
const takeNumber = (numberToConvert) => Number((Math.round(numberToConvert * 100) / 100).toFixed(2))

takeNumber(150) // should return 150.00
```

What else can I do? Wrapping it in parseFloat doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Why? As a number, `150 === 150.00`. The only reason to have the decimal digits is for display purposes, for which a string should be fine.

Comment: You will not have leading or trailing zeroes on an integer/float because they are non-significant digits. As Nick said above, using a string will be your only way to keep them in if you need them. If you try to create a number with NS zeroes, you will see that they get removed after initialization when reusing this var.

Comment: Every visible representation of a number is a string, always. A number is abstract, it can only be 'seen' as a string. It's difficult to conceive of where you would ever need a .00 representation of a number to not be a string.